# Incorrect scroll bar placement on some sites

Tags: support, bug, design, top-bar, scrolling

On some sites (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/), the main vertical scroll bar extends to the top of the page, even though the top bar doesn't scroll:
[image]
[image]

I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure that the scroll bar is supposed to be next to the scrollable area.
[image]

Comment: My Topbar is not sticky, so for me it works as intended

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was an option. I guess that explains why the scrollbar is like this (otherwise the scrollbar would need to change position depending on that setting)

Comment: I didn't see statistics yet on how often it is used. If I turn out to be a minority it could well be that the scroll bars get adapted to be a good fit for what is used by most users.